# Ubuntu 16.04 installation blank screen

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I know this is a common issue, and I've already searched and tried all I've found, but nothing works.
I've been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop but I can't seem to make it work. I've tried both with USB and DVD (both checked for intregrity) with no differences.

The USB/DVD boots, and it shows the UEFI selection screen (try Ubuntu, install, check disk, etc...). Whichever I choose, it goes straigth to a *blank* screen.

I've tried booting in BIOS (legacy) mode, and the only difference is I don't get the selection screen, just a brief purple screen with the little guy on the bottom, and then again, blank screen.

I've also tried with the following grub boot methods: nomodeset, nolapic, acpi=off, and different combinations of them. Some combinations shows some processes going on, but no luck, some of them go to a kernel panic.

Here are my specs:
Gigabyte Gigabyte GA-970A-D3P (no on-board video)
AMD FX6300
Sapphire RX460

Thank you!

[As far as I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNWtm.jpg)

Comment: Are you dual booting or single boot?

Comment: The HDD has windows installed but I plan to wipe everything out. I couldn't install ubuntu yet..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)